# Text extraction using sed or awk

Tags: shell, sed, grep

How can i extract the text betwenn 'title="Id: ' and '"' strings.

My Script :

```
#! /bin/sh

S='<TD WIDTH="15%"><a title="Id: A LA UNE HD" class="A3"></a></TD>'

fn_ExtractData() {
                  local DataField="$(printf %s "$1" | sed -n -e '/'"$2"'/,/'"$3"'/p')"
                  #local DataField="$(printf %s "$1" | grep -oP '(?<='"$2"').*?(?='"$3"')')"
                  printf '%s' "$DataField"
}
ptr1='title="Id: '
ptr2='"'
rslt="$(fn_ExtractData "$S" "$ptr1" "$ptr2")"
echo "$rslt"
exit
```

output expected :

```
A LA UNE HD
```

without leading or trailing spaces.

Best Regards.
PS. I have already a working command using grep.

Comment: Your script as written takes advantage of features that are present only in bash, and not the traditional Bourne shell.  As such, the shebang line should be `#! /bin/bash` instead of `#! /bin/sh`.

Comment: Also, instead of `printf %s "$1" | whatever`, you can just do `whatever <<<"$1"`.  The `<<<` *string* construct is called a [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment, but what your are suggesting is specific to bash, in my case i'm using sh not bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if your input is HTML, you should consider using an HTML parser.  Regular-expression-based tools like `awk` and `sed` won't be able to deal with arbitrary HTML.

But in your particular example, this will work:

```
sed -ne 's/^.*title="Id: \([^"]*\)".*$/\1/p`
```

Comment: fn_ExtractData() {
                  local DataField="$(printf %s "$1" | sed -ne 's/^.*'"$2"'\([^'"$3"']*\)'"$3"'.*$/\1/p')"
                  printf '%s' "$DataField"
}   Chapeau it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, grep has `-Po` option, so you can get the result directly with grep

```
S='<TD WIDTH="15%"><a title="Id: A LA UNE HD" class="A3"></a></TD>'
grep -Po 'title="Id: \K[^"]+' <<< "$S"
```

If you don't like the `\K` option:

```
grep -Po '(?<=title="Id: )[^"]*' <<< "$S"
```

Comment: in my embedded system the grep "P" option is not supplied. With sed it works without issues now.

Comment: You should always double quote variable: `<<< "$S"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk -F'title="Id: ' '{split($2,a,"\"");print a[1]}' <<< "$S"
A LA UNE HD
```